# Add ThumbToolTip to Slider

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

How to add a ThumbToolTip to a Slider (currently I'm working with Windows Phone 8.1 RT)?

According to [MSDN - there is a property that should enable ThumbTooltip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.slider.isthumbtooltipenabled.aspx). But as I've looked at [default style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709929) there is no sign of ToolTip.

I've tried to set the value to true (which is also a default value):

```
<Slider Maximum="100" Value="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
 ThumbToolTipValueConverter="{StaticResource ToolTipConv}" IsThumbToolTipEnabled="True"/>
```

But no ToolTip was shown. I can think of making a Control and bind it to Slider's value, but can it be done easier way?

Comment: have you tried it without specifying your own ValueConverter? That should display the value of the Slider as ToolTip

Comment: @Jehof Yes - it was my first try, then I've added this converter to check if that would change something. No ToolTip in any case and converter also isn't fired.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm stuck with the same issue

Comment: @pec1985 Nope. I've resigned of tooltip, due to lack of solution. I'm not sure if it's implemented, if not we will have to implement own control or wait for sdk update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default *ThumbToolTip* is not available for *Windows Phone 8.1*.

On *Windows 10 UWP* apps works fine.