# How to show slider tool tip?

Tags: c#, slider, windows-phone, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Any one knows how to show the slider tool tip on Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT? I have checked the property IsThumbToolTipEnabled but no tool tip is shown. I couldn't find any resources on how to do this on phone. Any clue?

Comment: SliderToolTip in the sense? Give me a brief how does it work? Is it kind of a normal tooltip or what?

Comment: Its the tool tip which appears right on top of the slider thumb.See windows volume bar you'll get it.When you click and drag the volume bar it shows the current volume in the tool-tip.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add ThumbToolTip to Slider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264743/add-thumbtooltip-to-slider)

Answer (score 0):

Set a custom template and use the tooltipservice api.

First, edit the style for a slider. Next find the `<Thumb>` Element. This code will work and show the text, and you can use binding for the text value.

```
<Thumb>
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <TextBlock Text="Your text"/>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Thumb>
```

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. A sample would be great!